# Spring data redis returns null on deserializing List type

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am using spring data redis and one of my entity has a list as below.

```
@RedisHash("person")
@Data
@Builder
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String name;
    private List<Address> addressList;

}

public class Address implements Serializable {

    private String postCode;
    private String country;

}
```

The serialisation works fine and the address is stored as

```
 HGETALL person:123456
 "name"
 "blabla"
 "address[0].postCode"
 "1111XX"
 "address[1].country"
 "IN"
```

but while getting the person back the List is always null ? could someone point out what I am doing wrong here.

My Redis configuration looks as below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, String> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        RedisSerializer<String> redisSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        mapper.findAndRegisterModules();

        template.setKeySerializer(redisSerializer);
        template.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, how you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have some suspicion but can you share a bit more code snippet on how you use redisTemplate to save the data into redis?

But most likely its because you set up both Key and Values initialization of RedisTemplate

`RedisTemplate<K, V>` as `<String, String>`

Which is why even with Jackson2JsonSerializer it can't serialize and deserialize the `List<Address>` class properly.

A possible solution would be:

```
@Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Person> redisTemplate(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Person> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();

        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

And then you store the whole Person object into Redis

When you need it then you get the whole object out and implement your getter and setter.

Hope this helps